# Recursive function to go inside dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I have to recursively look for dictionary whose values doesn't contain another dictionary and then create a new dictionary based on that,Currently my recursive function is able to handle dictionary of dictionaries

```
b= {'order': {'id': u'62211'}, 'no': 0, 'data': 340, 'instruction': {'id': u'99AA', 'version': u'1', 'validation': ('nota', None), 'time': 9001, 'instructions': [], 'restart': True}}

temp_1={}
import copy
def getKeys(d):


    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):

            getKeys(v)
        else:
            temp_1[k]=v

    return temp_1



a= getKeys(b)
Output
{'no': 0, 'version': u'1', 'time': 9001, 'validation': ('nota', None), 'data': 340, 'id': u'62211', 'restart': True, 'instructions': []}
```

but when there are instances where dictionaries are coming inside a list or tuple not sure how to handle that in a recursive way.

```
ab={'apple':9,'ball':{'cat':8,'www':('data',{'new':'hello','ppp':('dat',[{'jjj':'world'}])})}}

expected output:

   { 'apple':9,'cat':8,'new':'hello','jjj':'world'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just process `iterable` items(not only `dict`). Here an example:

```
import collections

example_data = {
    'apple': 9,
    'ball': {
        'cat': 8,
        'www': (
            'data',
            {
                'new': 'hello',
                'ppp': (
                    'dat',
                    [{'jjj': 'world'}]
                )
            }
        )
    }
}


def get_keys(data, result=None):
    result = result or dict()
    # dict processing
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            # not str, but iterable - call get_keys one more time
            if type(value) != str and isinstance(value, collections.Iterable):
                result = get_keys(value, result)
            else:
                # value isn't iterable - just set to result
                result[key] = value
    # list, tuple, set processing
    elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple, set)):
        for item in data:
            # list item is not str, but iterable - call get_keys one more time
            if type(item) != str and isinstance(item, collections.Iterable):
                result = get_keys(item, result)

    return result


print(get_keys(example_data))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if type(value) != str and isinstance(value, get_keys.Iterable):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Iterable',Got this error

Comment: @Awin yes. I used 3. Which is python? Python 2.7.10 - works fine

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Instead of `type(data) in (list, tuple, set)` you should check for `isinstance(data, (list, tuple, set))` otherwise you might miss derived types (or check for `collections.Iterable` in general).

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_keys(x, tmp=None):
    if tmp is None: tmp = {}
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for key,value in x.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                get_keys(value, tmp)
            elif isinstance(value, (tuple, list, set):
                for item in value:
                    get_keys(item, tmp)
            else:
                tmp[key] = value
    elif isinstance(x, (tuple, list set)):
        for item in x:
            get_keys(item, tmp)
    return tmp


b= {'order': {'id': u'62211'}, 'no': 0, 'data': 340, 'instruction': {'id': u'99AA', 'version': u'1', 'validation': ('nota', None), 'time': 9001, 'instructions': [], 'restart': True}}
ab={'apple':9,'ball':{'cat':8,'www':('data',{'new':'hello','ppp':('dat',[{'jjj':'world'}])})}}

a = get_keys(ab)
aa = get_keys(b)
print(a)
print(aa)
```

Comment: You can simplify `isinstance(x, tuple) or isinstance(x, list) or isinstance(x, set)` to `isinstance(x, (tuple, list, set))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one function for processing `dict` and another for processing `tuple` and `list`. Depending on the type of elements you can choose which function to apply:

```
result = {}

def process_list(l):
    for x in l:
        try:
            process[type(x)](x)
        except KeyError:
            pass

def process_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            process[type(v)](v)
        except KeyError:
            result[k] = v

process = {
    list: process_list,
    tuple: process_list,
    dict: process_dict
}
```

Then just call `process_dict(ab)` for example.

Comment: result[k] = v
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @Awin Sure, since `result` should actually be a `dict` cause that is what you want to have in the end, right? Just as in your code example. So it was a typo in the answer.